# Qual o nome dessa tela no android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Gostaria de saber o nome dessa tela no Android para assim acrescentar em meu projeto .Agradeço desde já .

[image: A]

Comment: Deve ser ***DialogFragment***

Comment: Ou um simples `AlertDialog` com layout customizado, se você não estiver usando fragmentos.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigos,ambos me ajudaram muito em responder a pergunta feita : ) .

Comment: Alguém que faça uma resposta.

Comment: tambem pode ser uma Activity com android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
Possibilidades é o que não falta ;D

Answer (score 1):

Essa tela pode ser construída através de um "Custom Layout" de um Dialog, ou em um ["Dialog Fragment"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html)

Mais informações [nesta pagina](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)